# Issue faced in converting dataframe to dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a 2 columns (Column names Orig_Nm and Mapping) dataframe:

Orig Name   Mapping

Name           FinalName

Id_No           Identification

Group           Zone

Now I wish to convert it to a dictionary, so I use

```
name_dict = df.set_index('Orig_Nm').to_dict()
print (name_dict)
```

The output which I get is:

`{'Mapping': {'Group': 'Zone', 'ID_No': 'Identification', 'Name': 'Final_Name'}}`

So it is a dictionary within dictionary `{{}}`.
What am I doing wrong, that I am not getting a single dictionary i.e. `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) instead [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) by selcting `Mapping` column for `Series`:

```
name_dict = df.set_index('Orig_Nm')['Mapping'].to_dict()
```

Also working selecting by key:

```
name_dict = df.set_index('Orig_Nm').to_dict()['Mapping']
```

EDIT:

In your solution is after `set_index` created one column `DataFrame`, so function `to_dict` create nested dictionary - first key is columns name:

```
d = {'Orig_Nm': ['Group', 'ID_No', 'Name'], 
     'Mapping': ['Zone', 'Identification', 'Final_Name']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
  Orig_Nm         Mapping
0   Group            Zone
1   ID_No  Identification
2    Name      Final_Name

print (df.set_index('Orig_Nm'))
                Mapping
Orig_Nm                
Group              Zone
ID_No    Identification
Name         Final_Name

print (type(df.set_index('Orig_Nm')))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So for avoid it is necessary selecting this column to `Series`:

```
print (df.set_index('Orig_Nm')['Mapping'])
Orig_Nm
Group              Zone
ID_No    Identification
Name         Final_Name
Name: Mapping, dtype: object

print (type(df.set_index('Orig_Nm')['Mapping']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```